# conditional formatting in excel problem - help in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a macro to be used in conditional formatting. I need that if a row contains a cell that is 1, then i need that the whole row is highlighted (e.g. A1 - E1).

at the moment i only managed to highlight the cells containing number 1,  but not the whole row. any ideas ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in Excel, select A1:E1, then Format > Conditional Formatting... > Formula Is > `=SUMIF($A1:$E1,"=1")>0`. Don't forget the `$` dollar signs, to specify an absolute (and not a relative) reference to columns A to E!

This is the VBA code to do the same thing in a macro:

```
With Range("A1:E1")
    ' If you need to delete any "pre-existing conditions" 
    ' (no US healthcare reform pun intended) then uncomment the following line: 
    '.FormatConditions.Delete 

    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
         Formula1:="=SUMIF($A1:$E1,""=1"")>0"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow background
End With
```

Comment: from the comments and the question itself I understand that the criteria was the following "if is there any '1' in the row colour the entire row/range" not "if all the values sums 1 then color" so the formulae has to be changed to =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$E$1;"=1")>0;TRUE;FALSE) in FormatConditions.

Comment: My formula does what the OP asks -- it does not do "if all the values sums 1 then color" as you seem to suggest. To convince yourself, try it out! True, your formula works just as well.

Comment: True, looks like a miss a IF in my earlier inspection, my apologies